# Error in shapeless code: Expression of inst.type does not conform

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am reading the book shapeless and follow the examples.
On chapter 4, there is an example about, how to read the second element of `HList`.

The code

```
import shapeless.{HList, ::, HNil}


trait Second[L <: HList] {

  type Out

  def apply(value: L): Out

}

object Second {

  type Aux[L <: HList, O] = Second[L] {type Out = O}

  def apply[L <: HList](implicit inst: Second[L]): Aux[L, inst.Out] =
    inst
}


object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  }

}
```

The compiler complains:

[image]

I copy and paste the code from book one to one and can not configure it out, where is the error.

Please help me to find it.

Comment: Did you try clone code from related gitHub repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the compiler but your IDE complains (is it IntelliJ?).

If you compile (Ctrl+Shift+F9 / ⌘+Shift+F9) or run (Ctrl+Shift+F10 / ⌘+Shift+F10) your code you'll see it compiles perfectly fine.

You should get used to have some valid Scala code mis-underlined by IDE in red.

This is the way to convince your IDE:

```
def apply[L <: HList, O](implicit inst: Second.Aux[L, O]): Aux[L, O] = inst
```

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. It compiles perfectly but  the `mis-underlined by IDE in read` what does it mean?

Comment: It means scalac compiler thinks the code is valid but IntelliJ thinks it's not (actually not IntelliJ itself but the compiler it uses, which is different from scalac).

Comment: How to disable, or it is not recommended? I want only, the error from compiler not IntelliJ

Comment: What is the reason to use IDE if you disable highlighting?

Comment: OK, i see. Thanks so much.